# no toolbar and layout errors

Tags: 10, toolbar

[image: Drupal website (windows)]

Hi, I downloaded my first Drupal website using xampp following YouTube videos. *I am a complete beginner, with zero coding experience.* All my links do not work excluding the "get started" and "next steps". I am not provided with a toolbar like the YouTube example.

Does anyone know what I should do?

Many thanks,

Louis

[image: Drupal website (windows 2)]

[image: no tool bar]

Comment: Without knowing what steps you took to install Drupal, this question is difficult to answer.  However, for modern Drupal, it is way easier to get started with a tool like ddev (https://ddev.com/get-started/) instead of XAMPP, which requires some server knowledge.

Comment: XAMPP is not necessarily set up to run Drupal "out of the box". As a beginner you should use DDEV. Otherwise you have to read through ALL of Drupal's requirements, then check that every aspect of XAMPP is set up to those requirements. The problems you are seeing are because of XAMPP not meeting the requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your help however my system doesn't reach the requirements for ddev. (Lenovo laptop - cannot enable virtualisation) would this have an affect using XAMPP for Drupal.

Comment: The platform you chose must be set up for Drupal. Read and follow all requirements: https://www.drupal.org/docs/getting-started/system-requirements